# How to set image in ViewPager when images come from web server

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to set image in view pager i successfully done but in my application view pager image are come from web server. How i set image when image come from web server. [Link for web service](http://opencart.codeniques.com/shopping/?route=feed/web_api/slider&key=test123$)

HomeFragment.java:-

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

ViewPager viewPager;
CustomSwipAdapter swipAdapter;

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        viewPager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        swipAdapter = new CustomSwipAdapter(getContext());
        viewPager.setAdapter(swipAdapter);




    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}}
```

CustomSwipAdapter.java:-

```
public class CustomSwipAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private String image_path;
private ImageView imageView;
private int[] flag;

public CustomSwipAdapter(Context ctx){
    this.ctx = ctx;

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return flag.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
    return (view==(LinearLayout)o);
}
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swip_layout,container,false);

    imageView = (ImageView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);

    new Slider().execute("http://opencart.codeniques.com/shopping/?route=feed/web_api/slider&key=test123$");

    new DownloadImageTask(imageView).execute(image_path);

    imageView.setImageResource(flag[position]);
    container.addView(item_view);

    return item_view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    // super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}

public class Slider extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

            int sattus = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if(sattus==200){
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("banners");

                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){


                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    image_path = jsonObject1.getString("sliderimage");
                    flag = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
                    Log.d("Slider imaage count ayr",jsonArray.length()+"");


                }
            }
        }catch (IOException  |JSONException e){
            Log.e("Error ",e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    //    new DownloadImageTask(imageView).execute(image_path);

    }
}

public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>{

    ImageView bitmap;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bitmap){
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        String urldisplay = params[0];
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try{
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        }catch (IOException e ){
            Log.e("Error :",e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bitmap.setImageBitmap(result);

    }
}}
```

I am new in android developing please help me.

**ERROR**

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.catalyst.android.shoppingmazza, PID: 3550
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
     at com.catalyst.android.shoppingmazza.activity.CustomSwipAdapter.instantiateItem(CustomSwipAdapter.java:68)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:870)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1020)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1112)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:632)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:901)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:940)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your return value is always null in your `doInBackground` method

Change it to below code

```
try{
    InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    return bitmap;    // added
}catch (IOException e ){
    Log.e("Error :",e.getMessage());
}
return null;
```

Comment: I added your changes but app still crush

Comment: can you please tell me how to post logcat

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.catalyst.android.shoppingmazza.activity.CustomSwipAdapter.getCount(CustomSwipAdapter.java:50)

 at com.catalyst.android.shoppingmazza.activity.CustomSwipAdapter.instantiateItem(CustomSwipAdapter.java:67)

 at com.catalyst.android.shoppingmazza.activity.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:40)

Comment: Post your error code in question not here in comment and post total logcat

Comment: I can't post my logcat i post my errors you can find mistake

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91245/discussion-between-anand-jain-and-kunu).

Answer (score 0):

You can download picasso library from here http://square.github.io/picasso/
and can be used like this

```
//Initialize ImageView
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

//Loading image from below url into imageView

Picasso.with(this)
   .load("YOUR IMAGE URL HERE")
   .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this. Initialize a List in your fragment and make implement the following. You should not fetch images from your adapter as the adapter might be called multiple times in the fragment.

```
class SomeFragment extends Fragment {
   List<Bitmap> imageList;
   FetchImagesFromServerTask task;
   ...
   ...
   .
   .
    @Override
    public onCreateView(Bundle ..) {
     .
     .
     .
        imagelist = new Arraylist();
        task = new FetchImagesFromServerTask(); 
        task.execute();

    }

    ...
    ... 
    ...
    public class FetchImagesFromServerTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,List<Bitmap>> {


        @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
        @Override
        protected List<Bitmap> doInBackground(Void... params) {

            String buffer = "";
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            String urlString = "http://opencart.codeniques.com/shopping/?route=feed/web_api/slider&key=test123$";

            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line + "\n");
                }

                buffer = builder.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Fetching Images From Server", "Error ", e);
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e("FetchVideosTask", "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            List<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                images = fetchImages(buffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++ ) {
                Log.d("Image fetched:",images.get(i).toString());
            }

            return images;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Bitmap> v) {
     imagelist = v;
     swipAdapter = new CustomSwipAdapter(getContext(),imagelist);
     viewPager.setAdapter(swipAdapter);
    }


    public List<Bitmap> fetchImages(String urlList) throws IOException {
        JSONObject myjson;
        List<Bitmap> myImagesList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            myjson = new JSONObject(urlList);
            Log.d("", myjson.toString());
            JSONArray page1 = myjson.getJSONArray("banners");

            for (int i = 0; i < page1.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject movieObject = page1.getJSONObject(i);
                urls.add(movieObject.getString("sliderimage"));

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (String s : urls) {
            byte[] stream = getByteArrayOutputStream(s);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(stream,0,stream.length);
            myImagesList.add(bitmap);
        }
        return myImagesList;
    }


    @NonNull
    private byte[] getByteArrayOutputStream(String s) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        URL url = new URL(s);
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = url.openStream();
            byte[] byteChunk = new byte[8092]; // Or whatever size you want to read in at a time.
            int n;

            while ((n = is.read(byteChunk)) > 0) {
                stream.write(byteChunk, 0, n);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.printf("Failed while reading bytes from %s: %s", url.toExternalForm(), e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Perform any other exception handling that's appropriate.
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                Log.d("Recieved image", is.toString());
                is.close();
            }
        }
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }


  }
}
```

Create another constructor for your pageradapter like this:

```
public class CustomSwipAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context ctx;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private String image_path;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private int[] flag;
    private List<Bitmap> imagelist; */Make sure you do this/*

    public CustomSwipAdapter(Context ctx, List<Bitmap> imagelist){
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.imagelist = imagelist;

    }
```

Then in your instantiate method just set the image resource from the list of Bitmaps.

```
   imageView.setImageResource(imagelist(position));
```

Comment: No its not working for me please provide some more option

Comment: I created that code at the instant and tested it to fetch the images. What is the issue your are having? I will try to fix it if you can show me your logcat.